# Текст на всю высоту блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Может кто-нибудь подскажет, как можно сделать так чтобы размер шрифта в левой и правой колонке подбирался автоматически, чтобы заполнить столбцы на всю высоту (высота колонок равна высоте экрана) и чтобы скроллбар не появлялся. Загвоздка в том что число строк может меняться... Я сделал только пока что вот так, само меню делю как бы на половины и вывожу в два столбца.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ the_title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
        tr.border_bottom td {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
        }
        h5, td {
            font-size: 1.66vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h5 class="text-center">Меню</h5>
            <h5 class="text-center">на {{ data }} года</h5>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {% for category, foods in first_part_menu.items() %}
            <h5 class="text-center">{{ category }}</h5>
            <table class="table">
                {% for food in foods %}
                <tr class="border_bottom">
                    <td class="p-0">{{ food[0] }}</td>
                    <td class="p-0 text-right">{{ food[5] }} руб.</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            {% for category, foods in second_part_menu.items() %}
            <h5 class="text-center">{{ category }}</h5>
            <table class="table">
                {% for food in foods %}
                <tr class="border_bottom">
                    <td class="p-0">{{ food[0] }}</td>
                    <td class="p-0 text-right">{{ food[5] }} руб.</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    alert($(window).height());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: На телефонах может случиться ужас, если всё сожмется в мелкий шрифт без скролла) [в вашем сниппете этот эффект тоже виден] P.s. могу ошибаться, но вроде `соусЫ`

Comment: Задача стоит именно так(, и поддержка экранов меньше 20 дюймов не нужна.